# capybara not passing select parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am testing a form in a Rails app using Capybara.

The form has 2 select boxes, each with default options. These options are passed as parameters when the form is submitted in development and production, but for some reason Capybara is not submitting them in testing.  Capybara is finding the select boxes and the options OK, because if I put in non-existent options in throws an error.  But Capybara does not pass either a default or a selected option as a parameter when it submits the form.

The form snippet is as follows:

```html
<%= form_for(@reservation, :url => account_reservations_path(account.id), remote: false, :html=>{:id=>'dates_form'}) do |f| %>
       <tr>
    <td style:"text-align:center" colspan="2"><%= f.submit 'Submit Dates, Source of Booking & Room Preference', class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></td>
    </tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :check_in_date, id: check_in_date_id,  placeholder: "Check In Date" %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :check_out_date, id: check_out_date_id, placeholder: "Check Out Date" %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="1"><%= f.select(:source_of_booking, Reservation::SOURCE_OF_BOOKING, {}, {:style => "width:150px;", default: Reservation::SOURCE_OF_BOOKING[0]})  %></td>
      <td>
        <%= f.select(:bed_preference, @bed_options, {}, {:style => "width:100px;"}) %>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
```

The processing of the form submission by the rails server is as follows:

```
Processing by ReservationsController#create as HTML
```

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"7Q3jakPp91bleWe1qZQFGRvYTXIxj9AdIYbeVtrF3bg=", "commit"=>"Submit Dates, Source of Booking & Room Preference", "reservation"=>{"check_in_date"=>"Friday, 29 July, 2016", "check_out_date"=>"Monday, 1 August, 2016", "source_of_booking"=>"Email Direct", "bed_preference"=>"Queen"}, "account_id"=>"5015"}

But in Capybara the parameters from the select options are missing, even though they have default values

```
Started POST "/accounts/625262370/reservations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-25 18:23:59 -0500
```

Processing by ReservationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "reservation"=>{"check_in_date"=>"2016-07-25", "check_out_date"=>"2016-07-28"}, "commit"=>"Submit Dates, Source of Booking & Room Preference", "account_id"=>"625262370"}

The test code throws no error until the final expect page to have text Confirmed, so Capybara is finding the select box but just not processing it.

```
it "should add a new reservation for room category", :focus => true do
  fill_in('reservation[check_in_date]', :with => Date.today.to_s)
  fill_in('reservation[check_out_date]', :with => (Date.today + 3).to_s)
  select 'Twin', :from => 'reservation[bed_preference]'
  click_button("Submit Dates, Source of Booking & Room Preference")
  expect(page).to have_text("CONFIRMED")
end
```

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what driver and/or browser you're using during testing, invalid html can/will be interpreted differently.  The form snippet you have will generate a <form> element with <tr> elements as children (you also appear to be missing a start `tr` element around the date elements).  <form> elements are not valid children of <tr> elements and <tr> elements are only valid as children of <table>, <thead>, <tbody>, and <tfoot> elements, so to be valid your snippet would have to be something like

```
<%= form_for(@reservation, :url => account_reservations_path(account.id), remote: false, :html=>{:id=>'dates_form'}) do |f| %>
  <table>       
    <tr>
      <td style:"text-align:center" colspan="2"><%= f.submit 'Submit Dates, Source of Booking & Room Preference', class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.text_field :check_in_date, id: check_in_date_id,  placeholder: "Check In Date" %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :check_out_date, id: check_out_date_id, placeholder: "Check Out Date" %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1"><%= f.select(:source_of_booking, Reservation::SOURCE_OF_BOOKING, {}, {:style => "width:150px;", default: Reservation::SOURCE_OF_BOOKING[0]})  %></td>
      <td>
        <%= f.select(:bed_preference, @bed_options, {}, {:style => "width:100px;"}) %></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 <% end %>
```

Without valid HTML it's possible some fields are actually considered to be outside the form and therefore are not submitted with it.  I'm guessing you were using Chrome with your dev and production systems since it tends to be a lot more lenient in its interpretation of invalid tables and if you try firefox on your dev and production systems you'll find it doesn't work since it tends to be a lot less lenient for invalid tables.

Comment: Thanks very much Tom, that was evidently the problem.  My <table></table> elements were outside the form, and I had not included these in the code snippet.  I have brought these inside the form now, and Capybara is now successfully submitting the select box parameters.

Comment: @WillM You're welcome. For your reference - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element - is the table element spec.  Technically the content model is a little more than I specified in my answer, but the spirit of my answer is correct